# How to give permission to a local running Docker container Lambda function access to other AWS services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am now testing a Lambda function built from a Docker image locally. That Lambda function reads a table from DynamoDB and also upload files to Amazon S3.

It seems that I get an authentication error because my AWS credentials do not seem to be recognized in the environment.

This is the error I got when Lambda is calling DynamoDB.

```
{
  "errorMessage": "The security token included in the request is invalid",
  "errorType": "Function<Aws::DynamoDB::Errors::UnrecognizedClientException>",
  "stackTrace": [
    "/var/task/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.186.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:17:in `call'",
    "/var/task/gems/aws-sdk-dynamodb-1.96.0/lib/aws-sdk-dynamodb/plugins/simple_attributes.rb:119:in `call'",
    "/var/task/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.186.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/checksum_algorithm.rb:111:in `call'",
    "/var/task/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.186.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/jsonvalue_converter.rb:16:in `call'",
    "/var/task/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.186.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/idempotency_token.rb:19:in `call'",
    "/var/task/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.186.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_converter.rb:26:in `call'",
    "/var/task/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.186.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/request_callback.rb:89:in `call'",
    "/var/task/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.186.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/response_paging.rb:12:in `call'",
    "/var/task/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.186.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:24:in `call'",
    "/var/task/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.186.0/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:72:in `send_request'",
    "/var/task/gems/aws-sdk-dynamodb-1.96.0/lib/aws-sdk-dynamodb/client.rb:3728:in `get_item'",
    "/var/task/app.rb:89:in `block in process'",
    "/var/task/app.rb:83:in `each'",
    "/var/task/app.rb:83:in `process'"
  ]
}
```

I run this command to launch my Lambda function locally.
These are not my real credentials by the way.

```
docker run -p 9000:8080 -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAYADV775XXXXXXXXX -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=ZVhoRF/0Y74f6Czzt1cDazleyIbQFJgP8yaXXXX -e AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="ap-northeast-1" test:latest
```

Still, I get the authentication error.

Weird thing is that when I try to run the same code without the Docker container (in other words, running a Ruby script that does the same thing) with the same credentials set as environment variables

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAYADV775XXXXXXXXX
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=ZVhoRF/0Y74f6Czzt1cDazleyIbQFJgP8yaXXXX
ruby test.rb
```

The script seems to be able to access DynamoDB and S3 without problem.
Is there a special permission my local Lambda function should have in order to be able to call DynamoDB and S3 APIs?

**EDIT ①**
I forgot to mention that but the Lambda function is functioning correctly when deployed on AWS with the correct IAM permissions.

The code in question is open-source and can be accessed here:
https://github.com/tonystrawberry/lgtm-generator-rails/blob/main/lambda-jobs/app.rb

**EDIT ②**
After explicitly setting the credentials when initializing my DynamoDB and S3 clients, it worked.

```rb
## Before ##
dynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(region: 'ap-northeast-1')
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: 'ap-northeast-1')

## After ##
dynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(region: 'ap-northeast-1', credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"], ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]))
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: 'ap-northeast-1', credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"], ENV["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]))
```

But I don't pass my credentials when deploying the Lambda function on AWS but instead use an IAM role...
I wonder if there is another way without touching the code.

Comment: It sounds like your code is accidentally sending a session token along with the IAM user access key and secret access key. Is that possible?

Comment: That's weird. I do not pass any credentials on my DynamoDB and S3 client (see EDIT ②). Maybe it is passing something by default?

Comment: Well, the code needs AWS credentials to talk to DynamoDB. I would print the values of the various AWS environment variables from the Lambda function code running in Docker: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN, and AWS_PROFILE. Also, consider having your code print the results of calling STS GetCallerIdentity to understand what credentials it has.